# has_many :through with a foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, associations, has-many-through

I've read multiple questions about this, but have yet to find an answer that works for my situation.

I have 3 models: `Apps`, `AppsGenres` and `Genres`

Here are the pertinent fields from each of those:

```
Apps
application_id

AppsGenres
genre_id
application_id

Genres
genre_id
```

The key here is that I'm **not** using the `id` field from those models.

I need to associate the tables based on those `application_id` and `genre_id` fields.

Here's what I've currently got, but it's not getting me the query I need:

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apps_genres, :primary_key => :application_id, :foreign_key => :application_id
  has_many :apps, :through => :apps_genres
end

class AppsGenre < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :app, :foreign_key => :application_id
  belongs_to :genre, :foreign_key => :application_id, :primary_key => :application_id
end

class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apps_genres, :foreign_key => :application_id, :primary_key => :application_id
  has_many :genres, :through => :apps_genres
end
```

For reference, here is the query I ultimately need:

```
@apps = Genre.find_by_genre_id(6000).apps

SELECT "apps".* FROM "apps" 
   INNER JOIN "apps_genres" 
      ON "apps"."application_id" = "apps_genres"."application_id" 
   WHERE "apps_genres"."genre_id" = 6000
```

Comment: What SQL are you getting right now?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**UPDATED** Try this:

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apps_genres, :foreign_key => :application_id
  has_many :genres, :through => :apps_genres
end

class AppsGenre < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :genre, :foreign_key => :genre_id, :primary_key => :genre_id
  belongs_to :app, :foreign_key => :application_id, :primary_key => :application_id
end

class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :apps_genres, :foreign_key => :genre_id
  has_many :apps, :through => :apps_genres
end
```

With query:

```
App.find(1).genres
```

It generates:

```
SELECT `genres`.* FROM `genres` INNER JOIN `apps_genres` ON `genres`.`genre_id` = `apps_genres`.`genre_id` WHERE `apps_genres`.`application_id` = 1
```

And query:

```
Genre.find(1).apps
```

generates:

```
SELECT `apps`.* FROM `apps` INNER JOIN `apps_genres` ON `apps`.`application_id` = `apps_genres`.`application_id` WHERE `apps_genres`.`genre_id` = 1
```

Comment: That returns all the genres for an app. I need all the apps for a genre.