# Calling attributes of an associated model in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have three relevant models: Vendor, Item, InventoryItem. I'm having difficulty understanding how to tap into associations to return associated attributes.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many    :inventory_items
has_many    :vendors, through: :inventory_items
accepts_nested_attributes_for :inventory_items, :vendors

class InventoryItem < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to  :item
belongs_to  :vendor

class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many    :inventory_items
has_many    :items, through: :inventory_items
```

I'm trying to return the vendors who sell an item, and the price they sell it for. Here's my SearchResults index view:

```
<table>  
<tr class="search-table">  
  <td>Product</td>
  <td>Details</td>
  <td>Brand</td>
  <td>Code</td>
  <td>Vendors</td>
  <td>Price</td>

</tr>

<% @items.each do |item| %>

 <tr class="search-table"> 
  <td><%= item.product %></td>
   <td><%= item.details %></td>
   <td><%= item.brand %></td>
   <td><%= item.code %></td>
   <td><%= #how to return vendors? %></td>
   <td><%= #how to return price? %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Here is my SearchResultsController:

class SearchResultsController < ApplicationController

```
def index
    @search = Item.solr_search do
        fulltext params[:search]
        end

    @items = @search.results
   end
end
```

I'm newish at RoR so any input is welcome. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here is what is returned from rails console when given Item.first.vendors

> Item Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" LIMIT 1
>     Vendor Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "vendors".* FROM "vendors" INNER JOIN "inventory_items" ON "vendors"."id" = "inventory_items"."vendor_id" WHERE "inventory_items"."item_id" = 1
>    => []

**SOLUTION EDIT**
I had some fundamental errors in my model associations that wouldn't allow me to utilize those relationships. I cleaned up those associations by getting rid of duplicate fields (in this case :item_id and :product_code) and the answer below worked perfectly.

Comment: Where does the price method/property live? Vendor? InventoryItem?

Comment: Price is an attribute of InventoryItem. I'm wondering if my primary key setup is confusing active record. When I created the Item and InventoryItem tables I forgot to leave off their respective id's. These two tables should relate through the product code attribute, which is a column in both Item and InventoryItem tables. I don't believe it's a primary key in either though. Problem?

Comment: That could certainly lend itself to being an issue. You may need to declared the FK (foreign key) in the relevant model (not totally sure without seeing the full code/model relations). This SO question *may* help :) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222838/has-many-through-with-a-foreign-key

Comment: Very helpful craig, thank you. I cleaned up my model associations after looking at the SO question you linked to and got things working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to list vendors of a specific item, just replace :

```
<td><%= #how to return vendors? %></td>
```

With :

```
<% item.vendors.each do |vendor| %>
 <%= vendor.name %><br/> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hmmm... that code runs okay, but doesn't return any vendor names in my view. I checked my db to ensure that there all of the necessary pieces are there to actually return something, so not sure what to do. Any ideas for a good console test to see if I can make things work in there?

Comment: In rails console, try something like : `Item.first.vendors`

Comment: Tried that, seems to return an empty array. I posted my output from that in my question. Any idea why that array might be empty?

Comment: Can you check your actual DB to ensure that the join table (i.e., inventory_items) has the correct entries for the item with id 1?

Comment: @craig.kaminsky, yes I can, using a sqlit3 browser. Check out my answer to your other question, because I think you might be on to something related to my primary keys.